# how can I recover Dell Inspiron 1300 Internal HDD password?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, dell-inspiron

I have an early 2000s Dell Inspiron 1300. I set a password on the internal HDD, but forgot it. I contacted Dell Support but they said there was nothing they could do. I'm not worried about the data on the drive, as there is none. Not a single partition. The reason I want to recover it is because I'd like to reinstall an OS to the disk. I'd also like to because when I boot from an external drive it takes forever to start up because it's attemping to read from the disk. The disk refuses, and it keeps trying until it eventually gives up.

Comment: To my knowledge internal drives cannot be password protected. You can protect the computer with a BIOS password and you can encrypt the content of a drive, but an encrypted drive can simply be reformatted by removing all partitions. I therefor think your drive is just not working at all. Do you actually get a password prompt if you plug that drive into a working computer?

Comment: yup, when i get back i'll send a photo. Maybe its just a legacy thing?

Comment: when it starts up it says the internal system HDD, XXXX-XXXX, is protected with a password. enter the password to continue. After 3 failed attempts, it just aborts, and proceeds to attempt to boot something. I know that its not the BIOS password because that's a separate option.

Comment: LPChip - for the hard drives I have applied passwords to (Lenovo) , the hard drive contains data about the password so that the drive put in a different computer does not run. I know things change, but drive password continues to get more secure.  I get a separate prompt for my drive  - 2 prompts - one for BIOS and one for the drive.

Comment: "internal drives cannot be password protected." Yes they can back in the day, even if you move them to new hardware they are sill password protected.

Comment: I see. Interesting stuff....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard Drive passwords are meant to be secure, and manufacturers cannot retrieve these.

I suggest you write the disk off and get a new one as there is no simple way to recover the password.

That is true for the drives I have applied a password to - I have to keep a record of it.

Comment: this is true. However, I've heard of people who have, in one way or another, recovered the password. Maybe it's fake, but i still have hope.

Comment: @LennonMcLean - Those users were not using your device.  **You will be unable to use the HDD since it has a password**